# Looking for counterexample where $K \not \subset H$ and $[G:K] \neq [H:H\cap K]$

Tags: group-theory

I'm looking for an example of a group $G$ (preferably finite) with subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $K \not\subset H$, and $[G:K] \neq [H:H\cap K]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}$, let $H=4\mathbb{Z}$, and let $K=6\mathbb{Z}$. Then $K\not\subseteq H$, and $H\cap K=12\mathbb{Z}$ so that
$$[G:K]=6\neq 3=[H:H\cap K]$$
You can move down to $G=\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, $\,H=4\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, and $K=6\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$ since you prefer $G$ finite.